# Initialize member pointer to function in constructor C++

Tags: c++, initialization, function-pointers

I have this member defined in

```
class X
{
   private:

      int (TMyClass::*pt2Member)(float, char, char);
}
```

I would like to initialize this member to NULL in constructor. Is it possible this way:

```
 X::X()
 {
      TMyClass::*pt2Member = NULL;
 }
```

?

What is right syntax? My function is C++ non static.

Then, how should I write the setter?

```
// declaration
void set_pointer_to_function(int(*pt2func)(float f, char c, char c));


// definition
void X::set_pointer_to_function(int(*pt2func)(float f, char c, char c))
{
     pt2Member = pt2func;
}
```

is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign to the pointer itself, not to what it points. By doing what you are doing, you're attempting to dereference the pointer, which won't work in this case since it is a method pointer, and to where it points (and thus the side effects from dereferencing it) are undefined since you have not yet assigned to it.

```
TMyClass::pt2Member = NULL;
```

Will therefore work. Also, you can initialise it along with the constructor like follows:

```
X::X() : pt2Member(NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: Waitwait, they have different types. That won't work. Fix the types up first.

Comment: @fonjibe: `set_pointer_to_function` is trying to set it from a completely different type (a non-member function pointer, with different arguments and return type), which isn't possible. You'll have to set it to a pointer to a member of `TMyClass` with the same arguments and return type.

Comment: You don't need to specify the parameter names. You're declaring a new type, not an actual function.

Comment: @fonjibe: After editing, it's still a different type - a pointer to a non-member function. You need a pointer-to-member, `int (TMyClass::*pt2func)(float, char, char)`, to match the type of `pt2Member`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
class TMyClass;

class X
{
private:
    int (TMyClass::*pt2Member)(float, char, char);
public:
    X() : pt2Member(NULL) { }
};
```